# RedirectToRoute and RedirectToAction return wrong url with Areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a problem with my project. When I return a Redirect Page after login succeed. My expect link is: `/Admin/Subject/Index.cshtml`. But while debugging, the url is: `/Subject/Index.cshtml?Area="Admin"` and I get a 404 error.

```
return RedirectToRoute(new
{
    Areas = "Admin",
    controller = "Subject",
    action = "Index"
});

// And

return RedirectToAction("Subject", "Courses", new { areas="Admin"});
```

Here is my RouteConfig

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(name: "MyArea",
        template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapRoute(name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Main}/{action=Login}/{id?}");
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How does the SubjectController class look like?

Comment: https://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/mvc/return-view-vs-return-redirecttoaction-vs-return-redirect-vs-return-redirecttoroute

Comment: just change `areas` to `area`